# Does anyone know a software for solving graphs?

Tags: open-source, graphs, math

Does anyone know any open source software for solving math graphs? I just want a software that tells me the shortest path (solve the graph) for a graph with multiple vertices and edges. With different weights on each edge.

Answer (score 1):

This one has a graphical interface and solves shortest path problems using the djikstra algorithm:

https://github.com/Samuele458/visual-dijkstra

Here is an online tool:
https://graphonline.ru/en/

If you want to write your own software and just need a library:

Java: https://www.hipster4j.org/

C++: https://blog.sommer-forst.de/2016/10/27/solving-the-shortest-path-problem-3-boost-graph-library/

All of these are open source.

Comment: What about non-open source softwares?